# jquery calendars not displayed after ajax call in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when page loads calendar objects is displayed on the form.
but when I call a ajax function from onchange event to select a city the calendar is not displayed on page after the ajax call. The ajax code given as:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function redirect()
{
    window.location='adm_regemployeelist.php';
}
function selectcity()
{

    var empid=document.getElementById("empid").value;   
    var empname=document.getElementById("empname").value;   
    var addr=document.getElementById("addr").value; 
    var addr1=document.getElementById("addr1").value;   
    var city=document.getElementById("city").value; 

    if(addr==''||empid==''||empname=='')
    {
        alert("Please Fill Out Empty Fields\n\n");
        return false;
    }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","emp_registration.php?empid="+empid+"&empname="+empname+"&addr="+addr+"&addr1="+addr1+"&city="+city,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check in firebug if there are any javascript errors. Also see what output you are getting from ajax call.

Comment: wich calender you have used and how ?

Comment: just out of interest why are you using jquery yet hand coding your ajax requests?

Comment: @Rupesh : I use jquery calender with code as : $(function() {
  $( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   defaultDate: '-20y -1m -247d',
   minDate:'19/03/1960',
   maxDate:tdate, // today'sdate   
   yearRange: '-50:+0',
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true

 });
}); and called it as  <input type="text"  id="birthdate"  name="birthdate" tabindex="14"  style="width:300px; "   value="<? if($get_emp!='0')echo $employee_birth; ?>" />

Comment: also i cant see any calls to the jquery calendar function in your code. Have you got more code to post? Thanks

Comment: @NicholasKing : thanks to show interest..... i jst give the code of calender & calling code to that calender..... in rply

Comment: can you edit your question and place the additional code in please.

Comment: and also you will need to include you're Html too :-)

Comment: @harshal can you provide additional code..like html and how you initiate your calender

Answer (score 0):

I think you are replacing the html element with the id 'birthdate' by ajax call wich is placed in container . So your calendar is no more associated with the 'birthdate' which is refreshed. Initiate it again after you get the ajax response and have replaced the 'container'

```
$( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true, 
                      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', defaultDate: '-20y -1m -247d', minDate:'19/03/1960', maxDate:tdate, };
```